# What's the best description of relationship between coach/trainer and coachee/trainee?

Tags: sentence-choice

I'm a non native English speaker.

The purpose of this question is to find a good name for the web application I plan on building that would help coaches take notes of their trainees, finances, schedules, services and progress.

I was wondering how I could describe the relationship of tutor and student / coach and athlete / etc. and use one or more words from this explanation to name my application.

Though, if I broaden the horizon a bit, and say 'I need to explain relationships in a good way' I might use some words from that explanation.

I've googled a couple of articles that popup first when you type in 'relationship between student and teacher'.

I find interest in words like: membership, care, tracking, coach, trainee, student, notes, exercise, workout, competence.

And I find that I dislike words like: finance, money, management.

There isn't a single word that can describe this relationship like for example: first thing that comes to mind when you say that two people are together is love. But if such word existed I'd use it.

How would you explain this relationship in as few sentences as possible?

Also, I'm honest about my intention with the result of this question, though I might not be in the right place to ask this, and if so, please give me a nudge.

Comment: *Guidance, direction, help, advice, support, role modelling* are among the words you can use.

Comment: *Client* is another possibility. Coaches are often hired by the person they’re coaching.